# How to use angular 6 datatables with observable data from server side(MySQL&Java&Springboot&hibernate) or How to convert an observable to an array?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, angular6, ngx-datatable

see: ERROR am facing due to using mf.data ... when I remove mf from data {(mf.)data} system display well, but data table features wouldn't work.

**ClientsComponents.html:4 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at**

service method to get all clients : Using Pipe and map because of deprecated 'do'

see my imports :

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
 getClients(): Observable<Signup[]>{
    return this.http.get<Signup[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/clients/all')
    .pipe(map(data => return data));
    }
```

Component for getting clients from angular service :

```
showClients(enable: boolean) {
    this.showClient = enable;

    if (enable) {
      this.data = this.signupService.getClients();
      //this.data = this.clients ;
        console.log("Component : ");    
        console.log(this.data);   
    }
  }
```

HTML Data table template : **breakpoint** : *ngFor triggers :: Only arrays or iterables allowed here error...

```
    <div class="container">
        <button class="button btn-info" *ngIf='showClient' (click)='showClients(false)'>Hide Clients</button>
        <button class="button btn-info" *ngIf='!showClient' (click)='showClients(true)'>show Clients</button>
            <div [hidden]="!showClient">    


                  <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">List of clients</div>
                    <!--   start  -->

                    <table class="table table-striped" [mfData]="data" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="5">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 20%">
                            <mfDefaultSorter by="name">Name</mfDefaultSorter>
                        </th> ...
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let x of mf.data | async" >
                        <td class="text-right">{{x.fname}}</td>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getClients(): Observable<Signup[]>{
    return this.http.get<Signup[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/clients/all')
}
```

```
showClients(enable: boolean) {
    this.showClient = enable;

    if (enable) {
      this.data = this.signupService.getClients();
    }
  }
```

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(data | async) as array">
        <tr *ngFor="let x of array " >
        <td class="text-right">{{x.fname}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must subscribe to the observable, something like:

```
showClients(enable: boolean) {
    this.showClient = enable;

    if (enable) {
      this.signupService.getClients().subscribe(
         res => {
             this.data = res;
             console.log("Component : ",this.data);    
         }, 
         err => { console.log(err); }
       );
    }
  }
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/services/signup-service/signup.service.ts(22,2): error TS
Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Signup[]>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

Comment: is getClients() still returning an observable? The error indicates you are trying to subscribe to a subscription and not an observable. Did you remember to import Subscription from rxjs?
And i suggest you use @Ionita's version of getClients() you dont need the map/pipe stuff.

Comment: and I am at work now, I left my project at home, and I have tried @Lonita Bogdan version...and the observable doesn't seem to change its type. I also tried to pass the data back to component , as array, but when I log data array, it logs an observable. that's  why I thought converting an observable to an array would work, since the error complains about array and iterable.

When I use dummy data/hard coded data, data table works fine, sort functionality also works fine, but when I use sever side data it complains about data type used in *ngFor . Thanks.

Comment: Otherwise I might have to change the type of data table library(ngx-data table) I am using ...

Comment: UPDATE : this  is the error I get :

ClientsComponents.html:4 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed at

Comment: You need to understand what an observable is before trying to use it, you cannot convert an observable to an array, that just doesn't make sense. I suggest you take a look at https://www.learnrxjs.io/ first.

And are you sure you are getting an array back from your backend? What is written in the console (  console.log("Component : ",this.data);     )  is this.data actually an array?

Comment: it prints an observable @MikNiller.

 Obsewrvable just give the flexibility in data, it can work with different forms of data, Objects, Array, byte, etc.

 what I don't get is how ngFor is able to loop through an observable, of course there is a key carrying some value about object data that's used in the *ngFor however when I use the same array/data var for data table, I get error mentioned above.

Comment: How does observable works with *ngFor? how does ngFor knows the object and its key carrying valuable data and we don't get to see or know this data's where abouts ? 

like it use to be with rxjs map and do operators, and we can be able to manipulate data with ease, to our own benefit.

I read that pipe is the replacement for the reserved key word 'do', that has been removed for use else where needed by blue print code. thus used pipe.

Comment: If this line console.log("Component : ",this.data);     in my answer prints an observable, then i would suspect that you forgot to subscribe, are you sure you didn't forget to add .subscribe( ... to this.signupService.getClients().

Comment: I guess yes, when I use subscribe I get error mentioned above. 

{'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Signup[]>'}

thing is, I can display data in the table, but data is not Integrated with data table sort feature ... I  

{Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed at}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187269/discussion-between-mikniller-and-neo-sono).